# VACUUM FULL starts and finishes without errors but does not clear the table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

This problem occurs in PostgreSQL14.
While some query is running on some table1, and I run VACUUM FULL on some inflated table2 (which in no way relates to table1), it works without errors, but the table remains inflated.
I did not find any information about this.
Therefore, maybe someone has encountered such a problem and knows why it occurs?

Earlier, a few days ago, I was able to reproduce this using the pg_sleep() function. But after trying to reproduce it today, everything works fine. If necessary, here is an example of how I reproduced it:

- Check the original size of table2: `SELECT pg_relation_size('table2');`
- Run updates on table2: `UPDATE table2 SET str = 'new';`
- Check whether this table has increased after the update: `SELECT pg_relation_size('table2');`
- Run the query on table1: `SELECT pg_sleep(600), count(*) from table1;`
- After that, run on table2: `VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE, ANALYSE) table2;`
- And check whether this table has shrunk to the size it was before the updates: `SELECT pg_relation_size('table2');`

This is how I tested it and during VACUUM FULL runs, the table was not cleared. Unfortunately, I can't repeat it now, so I wonder how and why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to reproduce as long as your pg_sleep command is started before the UPDATE command finishes.

VACUMM FULL needs to copy into the new table any tuples which anyone else might be entitled to see.  Even though *we* know that the pg_sleep command will only ever involve table1, PostgreSQL has no reliable way of knowing that.  It could expand to looking at table2, in which case it would be entitled to see the pre-update rows from that table.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to reproduce and understood that it is related to transactions, and I also tested with transaction blocks in which I ran SELECT on table2 while UPDATE was working on table1 and VACUUM FULL also did not clean the tables although it worked without errors.
Thanks for your help.